# Select rows that are a second apart

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am collecting a bunch of records and each one has a timestamp. The problem is that I am collecting a lot of records per second and they take up a lot of disk space, and I don't need that level of granularity when the data gets older than a day. I still want to keep some of the data, let's say one record or so per second, and delete all of the other ones.

For example:

```
Row TimeStamp(in seconds)
1       2
2       2.1 <--- delete
3       2.4 <--- delete
4       3
5       3.3 <--- delete
6       3.95
7       4.5 <--- delete
8       5.1
```

This way I am keeping a record a second(approximately), while deleting all of the ones in between. Is there a way to do this using SQL?

I suppose one approach is to loop through every row and keep a global timestamp difference between them and save the rows when the difference becomes more than one second, although I'm not entirely sure how to do that in SQL.

Comment: For example just delete where TS second part is not 30 or alike if you collect per second?

Comment: Perhaps what you could do is subtract each timestamp from itself when rounded to the nearest second, then `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY rounded_to_nearest_second_timestamp ORDER BY abs(this_difference))` and keep any record where that is `1`. Other than that, I think you'd have to get really fancy with `LAG()` to determine a delete, flag it, then delete it. I think the rounding, difference, ranking, delete would be a little cleaner though, and easier to explain later on.

Comment: @JNevill That's a good solution for now I think. Maybe just rounding and grouping by second and just selecting a random one will perform better because there are a lot of rows and the order by will take a while, but don't know until I benchmark.

Comment: I could actually just have a timer in the insertion code and have another column called 'Keep' where it will get set on every row where the timer exceeds a second and then reset the timer.

Comment: I don't see why you keep 6 and not 7.

Comment: @gordon just an example

Answer (score 1):

If you need to keep only fixed granularity, you can use a calendar slot table (here generated on the fly using `generate_series`) and for each row of the calendar, join matching rows of your measurement table using date/time functions. When you have those rows joined and allocated for each calendar slot, you can use `DISTINCT ON` to choose the "best" row based on arbitrary expression. Like this:

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE measurement (id integer, ts timestamp);

COPY measurement (id, ts) FROM STDIN;
1   2019-03-05 00:00:02
2   2019-03-05 00:00:02.1
3   2019-03-05 00:00:02.4
4   2019-03-05 00:00:03
5   2019-03-05 00:00:03.3
6   2019-03-05 00:00:03.95
7   2019-03-05 00:00:04.5
8   2019-03-05 00:00:05.1
\.

SELECT DISTINCT ON (day.ts) m.*
FROM (
    SELECT '2019-03-05 00:00:00'::timestamp + (s||' seconds')::interval as ts
    FROM generate_series(0, 86399) AS s
) AS day
JOIN measurement m
  ON (m.ts > day.ts - '0.5 s'::interval
      AND m.ts <= day.ts + '0.5 s'::interval)
ORDER BY day.ts, abs(extract(epoch from day.ts - m.ts))
;

/* result: 
 id |           ts           
----+------------------------
  1 | 2019-03-05 00:00:02
  4 | 2019-03-05 00:00:03
  6 | 2019-03-05 00:00:03.95
  8 | 2019-03-05 00:00:05.1
(4 rows)
*/
```

Answer (score 1):

I would advise you to just take the first record in each second.  That would be:

```
select distinct on (date_trunc('second', timestamp)) t.*
from t
order by date_trunc('second', timestamp), timestamp asc;
```

If your timestamp is really a number, then you can use:

```
select distinct on (trunc(timestamp)) t.*
from t
order by trunc(timestamp), timestamp;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=9562adcf4258425c2590679be0c2bbbb) is a db<>fiddle.